# Proof of $\sigma^2\geq (\mu-m)^2$ without resorting to Jensen's or Chebychev's inequality.

Tags: statistics, inequality, median

I asked a group of undergrad students (engineering) to prove that $\sigma^2\geq (\mu-m)^2$, where $\sigma^2$, $\mu$ and $m$ are the variance, mean and median of a continuous random variable. For the discrete case it is simple. For the continuous case the easiest way is to use Jensen's inequality. But the students do not know that inequality.

I thought I had an elementary proof, but I was mistaken. Can someone reproduce the proof in this paper http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.1990.10475743?queryID=%24%7BresultBean.queryID%7D#.VCLQ2_ldXfs ? I do not have access to this one.

Thank you in advance,
Gustavo.

Comment: Are you sure this inequality is true? If I haven't made a mistake it is equivalent to $F^{-1}(\mu-\sigma) \leq 0.5 \leq F^{-1}(\mu+\sigma)$ where $F^{-1}$ is the quantile function. I don't see why this should be true in general.

Comment: Hi!  It is really true:
$|\mu-m| = |E[X-m]| \leq E[|X-m|] $ (Jensen)
$E[|X-m|] = E[|(X-\mu) +(\mu-m)|] \leq E[|X-mu|] + |\mu-m|$ (triangular inequality)
$\leq E[|X-\mu|]$
Then, use Jensen again:
$(\mu-m)^2\leq (E[|X-\mu|])^2 \leq E[(X-\mu)^2] = \sigma^2$.
In fact, the inequality can be tighten to $(\mu-m)^2\leq 0.6\sigma^2$ in a very hard way.

Comment: Gustavo: It is true, but your claimed tightening to $(\mu-m)^2\leq 0.6\sigma^2$ looks more dubious without extra conditions. Consider a distribution close to $P(X\approx 1)=0.499999$ and $P(X\approx 0)=0.500001$.  For your $0.6$, you would need a continuous **unimodal** distribution; see for example http://www.se16.info/hgb/median.htm

Comment: Oh! My bad! The tight version needs a continuous unimodal density indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $m \le \mu$ and the random variable is $X$. (If $m \gt \mu$, consider  $-X$ instead.)

Then $$E[X|X \le m] \le m$$ and $$P(X\le m) \ge \frac12 \ge P(X \gt m)$$ implying $$E[X|X \gt m] \ge 2\mu-m.$$

So $$E[(X-\mu)^2|X \le m] \ge (\mu-m)^2$$ and $$E[(X-\mu)^2|X \gt m] \ge (\mu-m)^2$$ implying $$\sigma^2= E[(X-\mu)^2] \ge (\mu-m)^2.$$

Comment: Can you pls explain why is P[X<=m]>=1/2?

Comment: @PeterR: half the distribution is at or below the median, by the definition of the median

Comment: Is this the one in the paper? This  one I did not know. Very nice indeed. I'll show the students this one after I tell them about conditional expectations. For now I found the one I was looking for. I'll post it tomorrow (midnight here). Thank you very much, this was helpful.

Comment: @Gustavo: the paper is pay-walled so I do not know what it says

Answer (score 1):

The [Cantelli's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantelli%27s_inequality) for the standardized random variable
$$ Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$$
gives:
$$\mathbb{P}[Z\geq k]\leq\frac{1}{1+k^2}.\tag{1}$$
$|m-\mu|\leq\sigma$ is just a straightforward consequence.

Comment: That is the one-sided Chebychev inequality which they don't know how to use yet =) But thanks.